# How do I find percentage for a variable in a data frame?

Tags: r

So I have data frame "BreastCancer" attached, and I am trying to find the amount of cases in "Class" (a variable of "BreastCancer") that are malignant or benign.

When I do

```
summary(Class)
```

it returns

```
benign malignant
   458       241
```

I found the sum by doing this:

```
res <- c(sum(Class == "malignant"),sum(Class == "benign"))
```

where "res" is equal to the sum of malignant and benign.

What I don't understand is how to divide malignant or benign by "res"

I've tried

```
res/(Class = "malignant")
res/Class[2]
```

etc.

I need help accessing the numerical values of malignant and benign basically. How do I do this?

```
res <- c(sum(Class == "malignant"),sum(Class == "benign"))
Class[2]/res
(Class = "malignant")/res
```

Both return irrelevant results

I got "longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length" as a return for `(Class = "malignant")/res` which makes absolutely no sense

Answer (score 1):

So my first comment is that you should avoid attaching data frames to your workspace. It may seem convenient, but it generally leads to bugs and confusion down the road.

Second, it's helpful to include in your question where you're getting the data. This happens to be a fairly well known one, but even so I had to think for a second. So I found it in the package **mlbench**

```
library(mlbench)
data(BreastCancer)
```

Following your first attempts, you could do:

```
x <- summary(BreastCancer$Class)
> x / sum(x)
   benign malignant 
0.6552217 0.3447783
```

But in R there are usually lots of different ways to achieve the same result. Other options might be,

```
> prop.table(table(BreastCancer$Class))

   benign malignant 
0.6552217 0.3447783
```

or,

```
t <- table(BreastCancer$Class)
> sum(BreastCancer$Class == "benign") / sum(t)
[1] 0.6552217
> sum(BreastCancer$Class == "malignant") / sum(t)
[1] 0.3447783
```